# Is there an easy way to call sleep and propagate exception

Tags: java, guava

I want to call `Thread.sleep`, and to propagate the `InterruptException` if indeed it's thrown.

Imaginary syntax:

```
Interruptibles.sleep(1000);
```

which is equivalent to

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptException e) {
    throw Throwables.propagate(e);
}
```

Is there a similar function in a common library (guava, apache commons etc).

Comment: how about not catching it?

Comment: @Henry and contaminating the entire source with the checked exception? No thanks buddy.

Comment: +1 for contaminating the entire source with the checked exception.  There's a reason all the Java built-in concurrency libraries do.

Answer (score 9):

Wrapping in a RuntimeException is likely to cause pain down the line.
This is a complicated topic, I recommend the relevant section from Java Concurrency in Practice to fully understand your options.
Guava has [sleepUninterruptibly](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Uninterruptibles.html#sleepUninterruptibly%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) which implements one of the standard idioms described there.

Comment: Having read the relevant section from JCIP I still don't see the point. Can you give me more pointers?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this.

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptException e) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

or

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptException e) {
    Thread.currentThread().stop(e);
}
```

but it usually best to let the exception "bubble up" to somewhere you can handle it correctly. Your IDE can make this easy by filling in the code you need for you.

Comment: Read http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html for more information about this.  Thanks to Louis for providing this link.

Comment: +1 for "Java theory and practice: Dealing with InterruptedException". I suggest also http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue146.html and http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html

Comment: Thread.stop() is depricated. Documentation states that "This method is inherently unsafe. "

Comment: @OrcunC It is inherently unsafe if called from another thread because you don't know where in the code it will be called.  If you call it in the same thread, you know exactly where it is called.http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/threadstop-really-stop-thread.html#!/2011/06/threadstop-really-stop-thread.html